# Java remove escaped double-quote

Tags: java, regex

I have a long Java String that contains lots of escaped double-quotes:

```
// Prints: \"Hello my name is Sam.\" \"And I am a good boy.\"
System.out.println(bigString);
```

I want to remove all the escaped double-quotes (`\"`) and replace them with normal double-quotes (`"`) so that I get:

```
// Prints: "Hello my name is Sam." "And I am a good boy."
System.out.println(bigString);
```

I thought this was a no-brainer. My best attempt of:

```
bigString = bigString.replaceAll("\\", "");
```

Throws the following exception:

> Unexpected internal error near index 1

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How on earth did you get such a string?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Everybody is telling you to use `replaceAll`, the better answer is really to use `replace`.

`replaceAll` - requires regular expression

`replace` [[javadoc]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)- is just a string search and replace

So like this:

`bigString = bigString.replace("\\\"", "\"");`

Note that this is also faster because regular expression is not needed.

Comment: Everybody is thinking "oh, I know how to solve this", then forget to see the alternative :) +1 for using a better version.

Comment: +1, i never use replace() ever, even in cases where i don't need regex.:(

Comment: Everybody focused on correcting regex where simpler would be just not using it. +1 for thinking outside the box :)

Comment: Thanks all :) Typical X Y problem. http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Answer (score 4):

Replace all uses Regular expressions, so add another set of `\\`

```
bigString = bigString.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"");
```

Explanation why:
"\" is interpretad by java as a normal `\`. However if you would use only that in the parameter, it becomes the regular expression `\`. A `\` in a regular expression escapes the next character. Since none is found, it throws an exception.

When you write in Java `"\\\\\""`, it is first treated by java as the regular expression `\\"`. Which is then treated by the regular expression implementation as "a backslash followed by a double-quote".

Comment: That will remove all backslashes, not just the ones preceding a quote.

Answer (score 1):

```
  String str="\"Hello my name is Sam.\" \"And I am a good boy.\"";
  System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\\"", "\""));
```

Output:

```
 "Hello my name is Sam." "And I am a good boy."
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to replaceAll is a regular expression. You pass \ which is not a valid regex. Try:

```
bigString.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```